# Error uninstalling IObit Toolbar

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, toolbar

I am getting the following errors and prompts when I attempt to uninstall IObit Toolbar from within Programs and Features.

[image: Error trying to uninstall iObit toolbar]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Might also try the Junk Removal Tool. http://thisisudax.blogspot.com/2012/09/junkware-removal-tool-jrt-by-thisisu.html

Answer (score 3):

If the IObit uninstaller is no longer present- you should be able to remove it by *reinstalling* it first (which would replace the missing files), then uninstalling it again.

You can install it from here:

http://iobitcom.ourtoolbar.com/